# Specify duration using the audio html element

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

I am using the audio HTML element to play audio in a webpage, it looks like this:

```
<audio src="http://www.mydomain/someaudio.mp3" preload="none" />
```

This causes the problem that the length of the audio track is 00:00 until the user clicks the play button.

Unfortunately I can't use the **metadata** preload value because the server the file is being 
served from does not support it.

Is it possible to specify the length of the audio track in the HTML instead or via JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
<script>
function myOnCanPlayFunction() { 
   console.log('Can play'); 
   alert(document.getElementById('myaudio').duration);
 }
function myOnCanPlayThroughFunction() { 
    console.log('Can play through');  
    alert(document.getElementById('myaudio').duration);
}
```

You check event occur in oncanplay or oncanplaythrough and duration property is length of the audio in seconds
 Hope this help!